# Dragging view shows errand behavior

Tags: android, android-layout

I am offsetting an imageview on Action_MOVE, by calling offsetTopandBottom(int distanceY) and also invalidating after every call.

But the frames are visible, while dragging the view on Froyo and Gingerbread. Any suggestion ?

```
/**
 * Called on ACTION_MOVE
**/
private void offsetView(View view, int distanceY) {
    view.offsetTopAndBottom(distanceY);
    view.invalidate();              
    view.invalidateDrawable(view.getBackground());
}
```

I also tried posting on each offsetCall, but it didn't work.

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            view.offsetTopAndBottom(distanceY);
    view.invalidateDrawable(getBackground());
    view.invalidate();  
    }
});
```

Should I do a postDelayed for redraw, or should I post delay the call to offsetTopAndBottom(int offset) ?

**SOLVED:**

Execute drawing and offset calls separately 10ms (or some other time <60ms) apart.

```
view.offsetTopAndBottom(distanceY);
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    view.invalidateDrawable(getBackground());
    view.invalidate();  
    }
}, 10);
```

Thanks Greg :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware acceleration is not enabled by default prior to Android 3.1.

Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest, either for the activity or the application.

---

UPDATE: If that doesnt work, I think Android delays the redraw until your UI thread goes idle, but in your case it does not ever go idle because you are constantly handling touch events. So you should try posting to a handler instead of drawing immediately, to give the OS a chance to redraw.

Try this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
private void offsetView(View view, int distanceY) {
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           view.offsetTopAndBottom(distanceY);
           view.invalidate();              
           view.invalidateDrawable(view.getBackground());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The above problem only occurs in < API level 11, hardware acceleration can only be toggled >= API 11, using setLayerType() method. Also, I have already defined android:hardwareAccelerated="true" at Application level.

Comment: Froyo accounts for 1.6% of market, you really want to spend time trying to figure it out?

Comment: Its happening on Gingerbread also. Please help. Its better if we figure something out.

Comment: OK sorry I didnt see that. I think Android delays the redraw until your UI thread goes idle, but in your case it does not ever go idle because you are constantly handling touch events. So you should try posting to a handler instead of drawing immediately, to give the OS a chance to redraw

Comment: Na, didn't work, frames are still hanging. :( Also, edited the question.

Comment: ok, a postDelayed of 10ms worked, the idea was to separate invalidate and offset calls some time apart, not visible to the eye (1/16th of a sec ~ 60ms). So, I am offsetting on UI thread and posting invalidate on Handler delayed by 10ms. I am editing my answer with a big thanks to Greg :)